# Show characters from private use area from a specific font

Tags: 12.04, fonts

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and I recently made a font but most of its characters reside in the [Private Use Area (PUA)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas). The problem is that some fonts were already using the PUA so that when I insert a character from my font it is rendered as a character from another one, like Linux Libertine for instance. Is there a way to change the default font for PUA characters that are displayed?